# Is there a ticker Formatter that avoids overlapping on a log scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to avoid the overlap of the ticks automatically using ticker? When I run the following code, you can see that there are too many ticks and they are illegible because they overlap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter, EngFormatter
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(num='design', clear=True)
ax = fig.subplots()

v = np.logspace(np.log10(80), np.log10(7e3), 2)
ax.semilogx(v, np.ones_like(v), color=(0,0,0,0))
ax.grid(which='both', axis='x')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter(unit='V'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(EngFormatter(unit='V'))
ax.set_xlabel('voltage')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you need every single tick labeled? That's your issue.

Comment: No; in fact, I'm aware that ticker is able to determine by itself the largest amount of possible labels without overlapping. In my example, maybe 70V, then 100V, 200V, 300V, 500V, etc. I can do it manually, but I think ticker should be able to do it by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need every tick then comment the line setting the unit for the minor ticks (the `set_minor_formatter` one) since that's what's causing them to show up. Without data, it looks bad, but if you truly have data that spans a large range (which would necessitate a logarithmic scale), then it will look more normal.

If you need more ticks, then you can use the tick locator to set ticks at the desired frequency (there are plenty of Stack Overflow questions about that).